# Use type that isn't exported

Tags: typescript

`library` is a Typescript module. It exports a function `someFunction` that is made for a very specific purpose. It is called with a string, and that string must be one of several values.

In `library`, `someFunction` has been defined with an interface that asserts that its parameter is one of several strings - `"value1" | "value2" | ...`. This interface is not exported.

Consider the following end-user code, which wraps `someFunction` in another:

```js
import { someFunction } from "library"

function doThing(text: string): void {
  someFunction({
    content: text,
  })
}
```

Typescript throws an error - rightfully so - that type `'string'` is not assignable to type `'"value1" | "value2" | ...`.

The best solution here would be to change the type of `doThing`'s argument to the same type that `someFunction` expects. However, the type is very long, and not guaranteed to be the same between versions. I'd like to import it - but it's defined as a property on an interface, and that interface isn't exported.

Without changing the type of `text` to `any`, how can I correctly type `text`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *conditional types* with `typeof` and *lookup types*.

## Solution to your Example

```
// Assume
function someFunction(arg: { content: 'value1' | 'value2' }) { };


// How to get type of content `value1|value2`
type Content = Parameters<typeof someFunction>[0]['content'];
```

## Additional Resources

I also have lessons on [conditional types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbVgPQDealg) and [lookup types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0zc_fx3vkk).